# Why does (int)55 == 54 in C++?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

So I'm learning C++.  I've got my "C++ Programming Language" and "Effective C++" out and I'm running through Project Euler.  Problem 1...dunzo.  Problem 2...not so much.  I'm working in VS2008 on a Win32 Console App.

Whats the Sum of all even terms of the Fibonacci Sequence under 4 million?

It wasn't working so I cut down to a test case of 100...

Here's what I wrote...

```
// Problem2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Project Euler Problem 2:\n\n";
    cout << "Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:\n\n";
    cout << "1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...\n\n";
    cout << "Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence which do not exceed four million.\n\n";
    cout << "Answer:  " << Solve();
}

double Solve() {
    int FibIndex = 0;
    double result = 0.0;
    double currentFib = GenerateNthFibonacciNumber(FibIndex);
    while (currentFib < 100.0){
        cout << currentFib << " " << (int)currentFib << " " << (int)currentFib % 2 << "\n";
        if ((int)currentFib % 2 == 0){
            result += currentFib;
            cout<<(int)currentFib;
        }
        currentFib = GenerateNthFibonacciNumber(++FibIndex);
    }
    return result;
}

double GenerateNthFibonacciNumber(const int n){
    //This generates the nth Fibonacci Number using Binet's Formula
    const double PHI = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
    return ((pow(PHI,n)-pow(-1.0/PHI,n)) / sqrt(5.0));
}
```

And here's the output...

> Project Euler Problem 2:
>
> Each new term in the Fibonacci
>   sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1
>   and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> Find the sum of all the even-valued
>   terms in the sequence which do not
>   exceed four million.
>
> 0 0 0 
>  1 1 1 
>  1 1 1 
>  2 2
>   0
>  3 3 1
>  5 5 1
>  8 8 0
>  13
>   13 1
>  21 21 1
>  34 34 0
>  55 54
>   0
>  89 89 1
>  Answer:  99

So I have three columns of debug code...the number returned from the generate function, (int)generatedNumber, and (int)generatedNumber  % 2

So on the 11th term we have

55,54,0

Why does (int)55 = 54?

Comment: FWIW, the Fibonacci sequence usually starts with 0.  0,1,1,2,3,5,...

Comment: That's Project Euler's fault, I agree with you. The algorithm I wrote does generate the leading 0,1.  But this doesn't cause any problem with the answer (being that its looking for the sum of even terms)

Comment: Since the double type has inherently limited precision you should be careful about using it for things like this because Binet's Formula
uses infinite precision to get the result.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Casting to `int` truncates the number - same as if you'd called `floor(currentFib)`. So even if `currentFib` is `54.999999`... (a number so close to 55 that it will be rounded up when printed), `(int)currentFib` will produce 54.

Comment: So I have a new question then, why does cout show 55 54 0 instead of 54.9999999 54 0?

Comment: Because cout << double rounds to two decimal places by default (or something like that).

Comment: AFAIK, it's something like 6 digits of precision. But the important bit is that it *rounds* to whatever the output precision is set to - so if your floating-point number is very close to 55, you're gonna get 55 unless you output full precision.

Comment: @Shog9 - Is it possible to have cout print with full precision or do I have to use a different function?

Comment: Yeah, you can use setprecision() and setiosflags() to affect the formatting. BTW - that would make a good follow-up question: you should post it (i'm not much of a wiz with iostreams, so i'd be interested to see what others have to say)

Comment: 55 in IEEE floating point representation (00 00 00 00 00 80 4b 40) is *exactly* 55. There is no round off error.
The error is elsewhere.

Comment: @an0nym0usc0ward - you are right about 55, but if you look at the code the function that generates "55" is full of sqrts and pows; this is certain to result in some inexact numbers.

Answer (score 14):

Due to floating point rounding, that 55 row is computing something like 54.99999.
Casting double to int truncates the .99999 right off.

On my machine, printing a column displaying `(currentFib-(int)currentFib)` shows errors on the order of 1.42109e-14.  So it's more like 0.999999999999986.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, short answer is that under no condition should (int)55 == 54, so you need to start asking yourself what the associated line of code is really doing.

First question: how strongly does `==` bind compared to a typecast?

Comment: The typecast binds harder, and in any case (int)(55 == 54) is 0, or false.  It's a question of using floating point in a naive manner.

Comment: David, look up the phrase "socratic method".

Comment: While I support the Socratic method myself, does it work with the answer/comment format on SO?

Comment: yes, when someone doesn't come along handing out the answers.

Comment: I am aware of the Socratic method, but this question seemed to be starting awfully far away.  Then again, Socrates had a rep for being tireless in march when he was in the army....

Comment: @A. Rex: I would agree that it only works on SO if the OP keeps answering the Socratic q's and others don't. The latter may require a notice to others. The former may require that other people don't post full and direct answers to the original question before the Socratic method has a chance to get very far. All in all, seems like a difficult thing to pull off.

Answer (score 4):

Shog9 has it right, using the type double for a problem like this is not the best way to go if you are going to cast things to ints. If your compiler supports it you should use a long long or some other 64 bit integer type, that will almost certainly hold the result of the sum of all the even terms less than 4 million of the Fibonacci sequence.

If we use the fact that the Fibonacci sequence follows the pattern odd odd even odd odd even... something as follows should do the trick.

```
...
unsigned int fib[3];
fib[0]=1;
fib[1]=1;
fib[2]=2;

unsigned long long sum=0;

while(fib[2]<4000000)
{
    sum+=fib[2];

    fib[0]=(fib[1]+fib[2]);
    fib[1]=(fib[2]+fib[0]);
    fib[2]=(fib[0]+fib[1]);
}

std::cout<<"The sum is: "<<sum<<". \n";
....
```

that should do the trick, there might be even faster ways but this one is pretty direct and easy to read.

Looking at it I realize that you could probably get away with a standard unsigned 32 bit integer as the sum number but I will leave it as is just in case.

Additionally your code makes a large number of function calls to the generate nth Fibonacci number function. A decent optimizing compiler will inline these calls but if it doesn't then things will slow down since function calls are more expensive than other techniques.

Comment: Yeah.  I could do the whole thing using ints but I decided to go with Binet's formula...

Comment: But Binet's formula is slower and has limited precision. Any operation on a floating point number is slower than the same operation on an integer and the sqrt and pow functions are not exactly lightening fast either. Part of the point of project euler, to me, is to learn ways optimize code.

Answer (score 3):

I agree 100% with shog9's answer - with the algorithm you used to calculate Fibonacci, you have to be really careful with floating point values.  I found that the page [cubbi.com: fibonacci numbers in c++](http://cubbi.com/fibonacci/c++.html) seems to show other ways of obtaining them.

I looked around for a good idea on how to make your implementation of GenerateNthFibonacciNumber handle cases where it returns the double 54.999999, but when you cast to an int or a long you get 54.

I came across what appears to be a reasonable solution at [C++ Rounding](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-10827.html), which I have adapted below in your code.

Also, It's not a **huge** deal, but you may want to precalculate PHI, then either pass it as a parameter or reference it as a global - now you are recalculating it every time you call the function.

```
double GenerateNthFibonacciNumber(const int n)
{
        //This generates the nth Fibonacci Number using Binet's Formula   
        const double PHI = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;
        double x = ((pow(PHI,n)-pow(-1.0/PHI,n)) / sqrt(5.0));
        // inspired by http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-10827.html
        return ((x - floor(x)) >= 0.5) ? ceil(x) : floor(x);
}
```

Finally, here's how I rewrote your Solve() method so that GenerateNthFibonacciNumber(FibIndex) is only called in one place in the code.  I also added the column with the current running total of the even Fibonacci terms to your output:

```
double Solve() {
    long FibIndex = 0;
    double result = 0.0;
    double oldresult = 0.0;
    int done = 0;
    const double PHI = (1.0 + sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0;

    while (!done)
    {
        double currentFib = GenerateNthFibonacciNumber(++FibIndex);
        if ((int)currentFib % 2 == 0)
        {
            oldresult = result;

            if (currentFib >= 4000000.0)
            {
                done = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result += currentFib;
            }

        }
        cout << currentFib << " " << (int)currentFib << " " << (int)currentFib % 2 << " " << (int)result << "\n";       
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not going to help with your real question, but you mentioned you're learning C++.  I would recommend keeping as close to ANSI as possible, for learning purposes.  I think that's `/Za` on MSVC (which is what you're probably using), or `-ansi -pedantic` on GCC.

In particular, you should be using one of these signatures for  `main` until you have a good (platform-specific) reason to do otherwise:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
int main(int argc, char **argv); // same as the first
int main();
```

...instead of any platform-specific version, such as this (Windows-only) example:

```
#include <windows.h> // defines _TCHAR and _tmain
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]); // win32 Unicode vs. Multi-Byte
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above suggestions not to use floating point values for integer mathematics are worth noting!

If you want integer "rounding" for positive floating point values so that values with a fractional component below 0.5 round to the next lowest integer, and values with a fractional component of 0.5 or greater round to the next higher integer, e.g.

```
0.0 = 0
0.1 = 0
0.5 = 1
0.9 = 1
1.0 = 1
1.1 = 1
...etc...
```

Add 0.5 to the value you are casting.

```
double f0 = 0.0;
double f1 = 0.1;
double f2 = 0.5;
double f3 = 0.9;

int i0 = ( int )( f0 + 0.5 );  // i0 = 0
int i1 = ( int )( f1 + 0.5 );  // i1 = 0
int i2 = ( int )( f2 + 0.5 );  // i2 = 1
int i3 = ( int )( f3 + 0.5 );  // i3 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the code for generatring, at times float number dont behave the way we think when used in a long expression...break the code and check it.