# How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, iostream, cout

In my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553974/why-does-int55-54-in-c) I was printing a `double` using `cout` that got rounded when I wasn't expecting it.  How can I make `cout` print a `double` using full precision?

Comment: Sadly most of the answers below are incorrect. I recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610161/full-precision-display-of-floating-point-numbers-in-c instead.

Comment: Note that there isn't really such a thing as "full" precision.

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually, if you print the double as a an integer, then you can be sure you save all the bits... (`cout << *reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t *>(&my_double);`) This is useful to save your data and reload it later with the exact same value, bit for bit. But in most cases that's not what the user wants.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: `std::hexfloat` is better than casting, but yes

Comment: @AlexisWilke Be **very** careful with that! Type-punning is, unfortunately, horribly broken in C++!

Comment: @NikoO [Type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) works just fine, at least as long as you don't go across many different processor types. It has worked since day one. I use it in my [libaddr](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr) project where I deal with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. See the Socket Example on the Wikipedia page referenced.

Comment: @AlexisWilke I would argue that "it might just randomly not work in subtle ways with your compiler and there is no 'good' way of doing it" qualifies as "horribly broken". In any case, it is sub-optimal to just post a snippet that "works on my machine" and not even hint at the fact that something wonky is going on.

Comment: FWIW: this question got some attention on a blogpost:
https://www.zverovich.net/2023/06/04/printing-double.html

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In C++20 you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
std::cout << std::format("{}", std::numbers::pi_v<double>);
```

Output (assuming [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) `double`):

```
3.141592653589793
```

The default floating-point format is the shortest decimal representation with a round-trip guarantee. The advantage of this method compared to the `setprecision` I/O manipulator is that it doesn't print unnecessary digits and is not affected by global state (see [this blog post](https://vitaut.net/posts/2023/printing-double/) for more details).

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ej48Wa)):

```
fmt::print("{}", M_PI);
```

The question doesn’t actually define what it means by "full precision". Normally it is understood as the precision enough for a round trip through decimal but there is another possible but unlikely interpretation of [the maximum number of (significant) decimal digits](https://www.exploringbinary.com/maximum-number-of-decimal-digits-in-binary-floating-point-numbers/). For IEEE 754 double the latter is 767 digits.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Comment: Too bad that even GCC 11.2 does not seem to implement `std::format`.

Comment: {fmt} works with gcc 4.4 and later

Comment: Note: to archive IEEE-754 compliance, the number of significant decimal digits correctly printed does not need to be so great. IIRC, it would be 3 more than the round-trip need.  17 + 3 for common `double`. After that, it might be many zeros.

Comment: That part is not talking about IEEE-754 compliance but about mathematical representation of the binary number in decimal.

Comment: Saw your rad blog post. Green check transferred <3

Comment: @PhilippLudwig It would be implemented by the library, not by the compiler.

Comment: @KeithThompson true, but wouldn’t this be the job of libstdc++ that ships with GCC?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I don't know the details of libstdc++; I'm more familiar with the C side. There's a GNU C standard library that's separate from gcc; other C compilers use glibc, and gcc uses other C libraries on some systems. libstdc++ does appear to be more tightly integrated with gcc/g++, so yes, the gcc release version would be relevant.

Answer (score 93):

Use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
#include <iomanip>
std::cout << std::setprecision (15) << 3.14159265358979 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Is there some kind of MAX_PRECISION macro or enum or something I can pass to std::setPrecision?

Comment: std::setprecision(15) for a double (ok or 16), log_10(2**53) ~= 15.9

Comment: std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10)

Comment: Should be `std::setprecision (17)` for double, see comments on @Bill The Lizard's answer.

Comment: for std::setprecision to work, #include <iomanip> should be included.

Comment: This answer is just misleading, because `std::setprecision` does not work as one would assume; e.g. `std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << 39927.887 << "\n";` just prints `39927.9`. You really should mention that the argument specifies the number of _all_ digits, not just the ones on the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 29):

Here is what I would use:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision (std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1)
          << 3.14159265358979
          << std::endl;
```

Basically the limits package has traits for all the build in types.
One of the traits for floating point numbers (float/double/long double) is the digits10 attribute. This defines the accuracy (I forget the exact terminology) of a floating point number in base 10.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits.html
For details about other attributes.

Comment: This header is needed to use `std::setprecision()`: 
`#include <iomanip>`

Comment: it should be `std::numeric_limits<double>` instead of `numberic_limits<double>`

Comment: Why do you add `1` to `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`?

Comment: @uvts_cvs: Because of rounding errors when printing.

Comment: @LokiAstari You can use C+11's `max_digits10` instead. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout/554134#comment52239614_554134).

Comment: Should be `std::setprecision (std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2)` , see comments on @Bill The Lizard's answer.

Comment: @AlecJacobson It should rather be `max_digits10`, not some arbitrary `digits10+2`. Otherwise, in the case of `float`, `long double`, `boost::multiprecision::float128` this will fail, since there you'd need `+3` instead of `+2`.

Comment: @MartinBerger in that case `<limits>` is also needed for numeric_limits but finding the right header is trivial if you have cppreference so its no big deal :)

Answer (score 26):

> How do I print a `double` value with full precision using cout?

Use `hexfloat` or
use `scientific` and set the precision

```
std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 - 1);
std::cout << std::scientific <<  1.0/7.0 << '\n';

// C++11 Typical output
1.4285714285714285e-01
```

---

Too many answers address only one of 1) base 2) fixed/scientific layout or 3) precision.  Too many answers with *precision* do not provide the proper value needed. Hence this answer to a old question.

1. What base?

A `double` is certainly encoded using base 2.  A direct approach with C++11 is to print using `std::hexfloat`.
If a non-decimal output is acceptable, we are done.

```
std::cout << "hexfloat: " << std::hexfloat << exp (-100) << '\n';
std::cout << "hexfloat: " << std::hexfloat << exp (+100) << '\n';
// output
hexfloat: 0x1.a8c1f14e2af5dp-145
hexfloat: 0x1.3494a9b171bf5p+144
```

---

2. Otherwise: `fixed` or `scientific`?

A `double` is a *floating point* type, not *fixed point*.

Do **not** use `std::fixed` as that fails to print small `double` as anything but `0.000...000`.  For large `double`, it prints many digits, perhaps *hundreds* of questionable informativeness.

```
std::cout << "std::fixed: " << std::fixed << exp (-100) << '\n';
std::cout << "std::fixed: " << std::fixed << exp (+100) << '\n';
// output
std::fixed: 0.000000
std::fixed: 26881171418161356094253400435962903554686976.000000
```

To print with full precision, first use `std::scientific` which will "write floating-point values in scientific notation".  Notice the default of 6 digits after the decimal point, an insufficient amount, is handled in the next point.

```
std::cout << "std::scientific: " << std::scientific << exp (-100) << '\n';  
std::cout << "std::scientific: " << std::scientific << exp (+100) << '\n';
// output
std::scientific: 3.720076e-44
std::scientific: 2.688117e+43
```

---

3. How much precision (how many total digits)?

A `double` encoded using the binary base 2 encodes the same precision between various powers of 2.  This is often 53 bits.

[1.0...2.0) there are 2<sup>53</sup> different `double`,
[2.0...4.0) there are 2<sup>53</sup> different `double`,
[4.0...8.0) there are 2<sup>53</sup> different `double`,
[8.0...10.0) there are 2/8 * 2<sup>53</sup> different `double`.

Yet if code prints in decimal with `N` significant digits, the number of combinations [1.0...10.0) is 9/10 * 10<sup>N</sup>.

**Whatever `N` (precision) is chosen, there will not be a one-to-one mapping between `double` and decimal text.**  If a fixed `N` is chosen, sometimes it will be slightly more or less than truly needed for certain `double` values.  We could error on too few (`a)` below) or too many (`b)` below).

3 candidate `N`:

a) Use an `N` so when converting from text-`double`-text we arrive at the same text for all `double`.

```
std::cout << dbl::digits10 << '\n';
// Typical output
15
```

b) Use an `N` so when converting from `double`-text-`double` we arrive at the same `double` for all `double`.

```
// C++11
std::cout << dbl::max_digits10 << '\n';
// Typical output
17
```

When `max_digits10` is not available, note that due to base 2 and base 10 attributes, `digits10 + 2 <= max_digits10 <= digits10 + 3`, we can use `digits10 + 3` to insure enough decimal digits are printed.

c) Use an `N` that varies with the value.

This can be useful when code wants to display minimal text (`N == 1`) or the *exact* value of a `double` (`N == 1000-ish` in the case of `denorm_min`).  Yet since this is "work" and not likely OP's goal, it will be set aside.

---

It is usually b) that is used to "print a `double` value with full precision".  Some applications may prefer a) to error on not providing too much information.

With `.scientific`, `.precision()` sets the number of digits to print after the decimal point, so `1 + .precision()` digits are printed.  Code needs `max_digits10` total digits so `.precision()` is called with a `max_digits10 - 1`.

```
typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;
std::cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10 - 1);
std::cout << std::scientific <<  exp (-100) << '\n';
std::cout << std::scientific <<  exp (+100) << '\n';
// Typical output
3.7200759760208361e-44
2.6881171418161356e+43
//2345678901234567  17 total digits
```

[Similar C question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

Comment: Great answer! A few remarks though: You're right that `precision()` sets the number of decimal places for scientific mode. Without specifying `scientific`, it sets the total number of digits, excluding the exponent. You might still end up with scientific output, depending on your number value, but then you might also get less digits than you specified. Example: `cout.precision(3); cout << 1.7976931348623158e+308; // "1.8e+308"` Results for `printf` may be different. Confusing stuff one should be aware off.

Comment: For posterity, here's the required buffer length for guaranteed exact string representation of all double numbers in scientific mode using printf: `char buf[DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 3 + 5]; sprintf(buf, "%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, d);` The extra characters are for: sign, decimal point, trailing zero, e[+|-], 3 digits for the exponent (DBL_MAX_10_EXP = 308). Hence the total number of required characters is 25.

Comment: Can't edit my first comment, so here we go again: Another issue with scientific mode is that it might decide to not use exponential output, it even might decide to not use floating point output at all. That is, it will output 1.0 as "1", which might be a problem in a serialization/deserialization context. You can force it to output a decimal point by using "%#.*g", but this has the drawback that it adds a number of trailing zeros, which it doesn't without the #...

Comment: *"Whatever N (precision) is chosen, there will not be a one-to-one mapping between double and decimal text."* - That's incorrect. **Any** floating point value has an exact, finite representation in decimal. The opposite isn't true, though. There is no finite representation for the decimal value `0.1` as a floating point value, for example.

Comment: @IInspectable True that [all finite FP can be converted to decimal text](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485), yet not certainly with `std::cout <<`. Only rare implementations will do so for all `std::cout.precision(n)`.  IEEE 754 only requires about at least dbl::max_digits10 + 3.  As "one-to-one mapping between double and decimal text" refers to both conversion directions, we agree one direction possible maps yet the other does not.

Comment: Fair enough, *"mapping between X and Y"* does suggest a bijective relationship, which apparently escaped me back when I left the comment.

Comment: @Ruslan regarding [It should rather be max_digits10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout/52299693?noredirect=1#comment99267839_554780):  --> yes, for the total number of _significant_ decimal digits.  With `std::scientific`, `1 + setprecision` is the number of significant digits printed.  Recommend this answer's  `std::scientific` and `cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10 - 1);`

Comment: Thank you. In case it helps anyone else, here is code that restores precision and flags for floating point `T`. `const auto prec0 = os.precision(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 - 1); const auto flags0 = os.setf(std::ios_base::scientific, std::ios_base::floatfield); os << x; os.flags(flags0); os.precision(prec0);`

Answer (score 14):

The iostreams way is kind of clunky.  I prefer using [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) because it calculates the right precision for me.  And [it's fast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#performance), too.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using boost::lexical_cast;
using std::string;

double d = 3.14159265358979;
cout << "Pi: " << lexical_cast<string>(d) << endl;
```

Output:

> Pi: 3.14159265358979

Comment: The boost documentation says "For numerics that have a corresponding specialization of std::numeric_limits, the current version now chooses a precision to match".  This seems like the easiest way to get the max precision.  (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/changes.html)

Comment: Link with boost::lexical_cast (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) is dead.

Comment: Note that printing a `double` with only 15 digits as with "Pi: 3.14159265358979" might not convert back to the same `double`.  To always do that requires more like [max_digits10](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) significant digits.

Answer (score 11):

By full precision, I assume mean enough precision to show the best approximation to the intended value, but it should be pointed out that `double` is stored using base 2 representation and base 2 can't represent something as trivial as `1.1` exactly.  The only way to get the **full-full** precision of the actual double (with NO ROUND OFF ERROR) is to print out the binary bits (or hex nybbles).

One way of doing that is using a `union` to type-pun the `double` to a integer and then printing the integer, since integers do not suffer from truncation or round-off issues. (Type punning like this is not supported by the C++ standard, but it is supported in C. However, most C++ compilers will probably print out the correct value anyways.  I think g++ supports this.)

```
union {
    double d;
    uint64_t u64;
} x;
x.d = 1.1;
std::cout << std::hex << x.u64;
```

This will give you the 100% accurate precision of the double... and be utterly unreadable because humans can't read IEEE double format !  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has a good write up on how to interpret the binary bits.

In newer C++, you can do

```
std::cout << std::hexfloat << 1.1;
```

Comment: variant with union will give you undefined behavior because it attempts to read uninitialized value `x.u64`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how to display a double with full precision:

```
double d = 100.0000000000005;
int precision = std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10;
std::cout << std::setprecision(precision) << d << std::endl;
```

This displays:

> 100.0000000000005

max_digits10 is the number of digits that are necessary to uniquely represent all distinct double values. max_digits10 represents the number of digits before and after the decimal point.

**Don't use set_precision(max_digits10) with std::fixed.**
On fixed notation, set_precision() sets the number of digits **only after** the decimal point. This is incorrect as max_digits10 represents the number of digits **before** and **after** the decimal point.

```
double d = 100.0000000000005;
int precision = std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << d << std::endl;
```

This displays incorrect result:

> 100.00000000000049738

Note: Header files required

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
```

Comment: This happens because `100.0000000000005` isn't being represented exactly as a `double`. (It might seem like it should, but it doesn't, because it gets [normalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), i.e. its binary representation). To see this, try: `100.0000000000005 - 100`. We get `4.973799150320701e-13`.

Answer (score 7):

**C++20 `std::format`**

This great new C++ library feature has the advantage of not affecting the state of `std::cout` as `std::setprecision` does:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:.2} {:.3}\n", 3.1415, 3.1415);
}
```

Expected output:

```
3.14 3.142
```

As mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65329803/895245 if you don't pass the precision explicitly it prints the shortest decimal representation with a round-trip guarantee. TODO understand in more detail how it compares to: `dbl::max_digits10` as shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/554134/895245 with `{:.{}}`:

```
#include <format>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{:.{}}\n",
        3.1415926535897932384626433, dbl::max_digits10);
}
```

See also:

- [Set back default floating point print precision in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560291/set-back-default-floating-point-print-precision-in-c/53673686#53673686) for how to restore the initial precision in pre-c++20
- [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf/57286312#57286312)
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification

Answer (score 4):

[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point values are stored using base 2 representation. Any base 2 number can be represented as a decimal (base 10) to full precision. None of the proposed answers, however, do. They **all** truncate the decimal value.

This seems to be due to a misinterpretation of what [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10) represents:

> The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10` is the number of base-10 digits that are necessary to uniquely represent all distinct values of the type `T`.

In other words: It's the (worst-case) number of digits required to output if you want to roundtrip from binary to decimal to binary, without losing any information. If you output at least `max_digits10` decimals and reconstruct a floating point value, you are guaranteed to get the exact same binary representation you started with.

What's important: `max_digits10` in general neither yields the shortest decimal, nor is it sufficient to represent the full precision. I'm not aware of a constant in the C++ Standard Library that encodes the maximum number of decimal digits required to contain the full precision of a floating point value. I believe it's something like 767 for `double`s<sup>1</sup>. One way to output a floating point value with full precision would be to use a sufficiently large value for the precision, [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/K6c0_l)<sup>2</sup>, and have the library strip any trailing zeros:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double d = 0.1;
    std::cout.precision(767);
    std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the following output, that contains the full precision:

```
d = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Note that this has significantly more decimals than `max_digits10` would suggest.

---

While that answers the question that was asked, a far more common goal would be to get the *shortest* decimal representation of any given floating point value, that retains all information. Again, I'm not aware of any way to instruct the Standard I/O library to output that value. Starting with C++17 the possibility to do that conversion has finally arrived in C++ in the form of [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars). By default, it produces the shortest decimal representation of any given floating point value that retains the entire information.

Its interface is a bit clunky, and you'd probably want to wrap this up into a function template that returns something you can output to `std::cout` (like a `std::string`), e.g.

```cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
std::string to_string(T value)
{
    // 24 characters is the longest decimal representation of any double value
    std::array<char, 24> buffer {};
    auto const res { std::to_chars(buffer.data(), buffer.data() + buffer.size(), value) };
    if (res.ec == std::errc {})
    {
        // Success
        return std::string(buffer.data(), res.ptr);
    }

    // Error
    return { "FAILED!" };
}

int main()
{
    auto value { 0.1f };
    std::cout << to_string(value) << std::endl;
    value = std::nextafter(value, INFINITY);
    std::cout << to_string(value) << std::endl;
    value = std::nextafter(value, INFINITY);
    std::cout << to_string(value) << std::endl;
}
```

This would print out (using [Microsoft's C++ Standard Library](https://github.com/microsoft/STL)):

```
0.1
0.10000001
0.10000002
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *From Stephan T. Lavavej's CppCon 2019 talk titled [Floating-Point <charconv>: Making Your Code 10x Faster With C++17's Final Boss](https://youtu.be/4P_kbF0EbZM?t=688). (The entire talk is worth watching.)*

<sup>2</sup> *This would also require using a combination of `scientific` and `fixed`, whichever is shorter. I'm not aware of a way to set this mode using the C++ Standard I/O library.*

Comment: @chu That assumes that the smallest representable value is also the one with the longest sequence of digits in decimal. That sounds plausible, but plausibility is not quite where floating point values are at home. Have you tried to use [nextafter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) to see, if the lengths increase in the vicinity of `DBL_TRUE_MIN`?

Comment: @chu Ah, true, `DBL_TRUE_MIN` only has its least significant bit set in the mantissa. Hadn't thought of that. Still, I'd need to see a mathematical proof to understand, why that would result in the longest decimal sequence.

Comment: Note: "One way to output a floating point value with full precision would be to use a sufficiently large value for the precision," --> A library compliant to IEEE 754 need only print the correctly rounded value to `long double::max_digits10` + 3 significant digits.  We might not get full precision.

Comment: "I'd need to see a mathematical proof to understand" --> sounds like a good question on some site - and a bit of work to fulfill - too much for a  quick comment.

Comment: Yes `DBL_MIN - DBL_TRUE_MIN` took 767 significant digits.

Comment: @chu *"A library compliant to IEEE 754 need only print the correctly rounded value to `long double::max_digits10` + 3 significant digits."* - I wasn't able to find this requirement in the C++ Standard text. Is this incorporated from C, and if so, do you happen to know where I can find that?

Comment: IInspectable, the spec is a IEEE 754 one (sec 5.12), not a C++ one.  C++ may follow IEEE754 to various degrees of compliance.  [limit, H, shall be such that H ≥ M+3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087221/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%.12f", M_PI);
```

%.12f means floating point, with precision of 12 digits.

Comment: This is not "using cout".

Comment: 12 digits is not "full precision"

Answer (score 1):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53683457/3882652) there is a description on how to convert a double to string losselessly (in Octave, but it can be easily reproduced in C++). De idea is to have a short human readable description of the float and a losseless description in hexa form, for instance: pi -> 3.14{54442d18400921fb}.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use `std::setprecision`, and the solution works like this:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double a = 34.34322;
    std::cout<<std::fixed<<a<<std::setprecision(0)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: you do not need to use `cout.setprecision` to do it and I fill up 0 at `std::setprecision` because it must have a argument.

Comment: With this answer, for `double pi = 3.141592653589793` it prints `3.141593` with Apple clang version 13.1.6  .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works for any floating-point type, not just `double`, and also puts the stream back the way it was found afterwards. Unfortunately it won't interact well with threads, but that's the nature of iostreams. You'll need these includes at the start of your file:

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
```

Here's the function, you could it in a header file if you use it a lot:

```
template <class T>
void printVal(std::ostream& os, T val)
{
    auto oldFlags = os.flags();
    auto oldPrecision = os.precision();

    os.flags(oldFlags & ~std::ios_base::floatfield);
    os.precision(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10);
    os << val;
    
    os.flags(oldFlags);
    os.precision(oldPrecision);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
double d = foo();
float f = bar();
printVal(std::cout, d);
printVal(std::cout, f);
```

If you want to be able to use the normal insertion `<<` operator, you can use this extra wrapper code:

```
template <class T>
struct PrintValWrapper { T val; };
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, PrintValWrapper<T> pvw) {
    printVal(os, pvw.val);
    return os;
}
template <class T>
PrintValWrapper<T> printIt(T val) {
    return PrintValWrapper<T>{val};
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
double d = foo();
float f = bar();
std::cout << "The values are: " << printIt(d) << ", " << printIt(f) << '\n';
```

Answer (score -1):

**This will show the value up to two decimal places after the dot.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

double d = 2.0;
int n = 2;
cout << fixed << setprecision(n) << d;
```

**See here:** [Fixed-point notation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fixed-point-and-floating-point-number-representations)

[std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)

> Use fixed floating-point notation Sets the floatfield format flag for
> the str stream to fixed.
>
> When floatfield is set to fixed, floating-point values are written
> using fixed-point notation: the value is represented with exactly as
> many digits in the decimal part as specified by the precision field
> (precision) and with no exponent part.

[std::setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

> Set decimal precision Sets the decimal precision to be used to format
> floating-point values on output operations.

**If you're familiar with the IEEE standard for representing the floating-points, you would know that it is impossible to show floating-points with full-precision out of the scope of the standard**, that is to say, it will always result in a rounding of the real value.

*You need to first check whether the value is within the scope*, if yes, then use:

```
cout << defaultfloat << d ;
```

[std::defaultfloat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/defaultfloat/)

> Use default floating-point notation Sets the floatfield format flag
> for the str stream to defaultfloat.
>
> When floatfield is set to defaultfloat, floating-point values are
> written using the default notation: the representation uses as many
> meaningful digits as needed up to the stream's decimal precision
> (precision), counting both the digits before and after the decimal
> point (if any).

That is also the default behavior of `cout`, which means you don't use it explicitly.

Comment: It should be setprecision and not setprecison. Note: the edition proposal is blocked because it contains less than 6 characters!

Answer (score -2):

Most portably...

```
#include <limits>

using std::numeric_limits;

    ...
    cout.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
    cout << d;
```

Comment: I'm curious: why the "+1"?

Answer (score -2):

With ostream::precision(int)

```
cout.precision( numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
cout << M_PI << ", " << M_E << endl;
```

will yield

```
3.141592653589793, 2.718281828459045
```

Why you have to say "+1" I have no clue, but the extra digit you get out of it is correct.

Comment: numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits10 equals to 2. Because it can contain any decimal number of two digits 0..99. It can also contain 255.. but not 256, 257... 300 etc. this is why digits10 is not 3! I think "+1" is added to overcome something like this.