#  double truncates at 7 characters of output

Tags: c++

```
double fat = 0.2654654645486684646846865584656566554566556564654654899866223625564668186456564564664564;
cout<<fat<<endl;
```

results in:

> 0.265465

Should it be 7 charcters longer?  I thought that a double could hold more than that?

I also get the same result of a "long double".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're just seeing the default precision used by an `iostream`.

To improve things, use [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

```
const int max_digits = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10;

std::cout << std::setprecision(max_digits) << fat << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10)` for maximum precision

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10) << fat << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

- you only get 7 significant figures because your cout stream is defaulting to a precision of 7, as the other answers state you can increase this to `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`
- double can only store a fixed amount of precision anyway so most of the digits assigned to fat will be thrown away (on most machines you will get up to 15 significant figures into a double)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `cout`, which defaults to a certain number of decimal places. You can set cout's precision and then add a `fixed` to give you the precision you need

```
cout.precision(15);
cout << fixed << fat << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cout.precision()`.
 or, you can also use `std::numeric_limits< double >` and  `#include <limits>` to get the maximum precision of a float or double..
see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout).