# C++ why I retrieve double as this format

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [double truncates at 7 characters of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996899/double-truncates-at-7-characters-of-output)

C++ why I retrieve double as this format

1.4547e+08

If i see the data itself, it should be

1.45470197.00

anyone got any idea how to convert that double 1.4547e+08 back to this 1.45470197.00

Comment: The format you given 1.45470197.00 isn't valid, there are no numbers with more than one decimal point. Do you mean 145,470,197.00?

Comment: FYI, that “format” is called [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: Please consider *accepting* answers to previous questions.  Do you really mean `1.45470197.00`, with *two* decimal points?

Answer (score 5):

If you're printing data with `std::cout`, use `std::fixed` to prevent scientific notation

```
double d = 145470197.00;
std::cout << std::fixed << d;
```

Comment: How do i use fixed for assigning the value to variable

Comment: @BaokyANewProgramer: You can't, unless you want to store it as a string, in which case, you lose your ability to do math on it. The double is not stored as 145470197.00, or as 1.4547e+08, it is stored as a series of bits in (most likely) [this format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).  The decimal number you see on screen is only how the ostream function chooses to interpret those bits.