# C++ How do I stop outputting the decimal and zero of a number like 5.0 using std::cout

Tags: c++, cout

I was about to ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout) question, and found a few more to ask.

How (according to the top answer) would I then proceed to only display this precision for a single call to cout, and then disable it thereafter?

Say I want to show precision for the first three calls, but not the last:

(I named a variable with the same name as the "fixed" format specifier in order to experiment)

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   using namespace std;
   int spam = 5;
   double flak = 5.0;
   double result = spam * flak;
   double fixed = 42;
   cout.precision(1);
   cout << std::fixed << spam + flak << endl;
   cout << result << endl;
   cout << flak << endl;
   cout << fixed;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke the precision function again to re-apply it like so:

```
int main(){
   using namespace std;
   int spam = 5;
   double flak = 5.0;
   double result = spam * flak;
   double fixed = 42;
   cout.precision(1);
   cout << std::fixed << spam + flak << endl;
   cout << result << endl;
   cout << flak << endl;
   cout.precision(3);
   cout << fixed;
   return 0;
}
```

Another way to do it is to use the `<iomanip>` header to use the [`std::setprecision()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) function and passing it to `std::cout`, so it would be similar to doing this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   int spam = 5;
   double flak = 5.0;
   double result = spam * flak;
   double fixed = 42;
   std::cout << std::fixed << spam + flak << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::setprecision(1) << result << '\n' << flak << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::setprecision(0) << fixed;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know what the precision was beforehand?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Initially the `precision()` is `6`. A better way to restore the original formatting is to use `std::ios::copyfmt()`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want. But C++ provides some ways to control the state of stream.

```
std::streamsize prec = cout.precision(); // store current precision setting
// some print here
std::cout.precision(prec)                // Roll-back
```

Comment: I wish there was a "scoped precision" class which restored it with RAII.

Comment: I was not aware that calling cout.precision() with no parameter returned a number. I tried 'cout << cout.precision();' and it did not output anything.

Comment: RAII wont help in this case because the changes need to happen within a function, unless you want to scope all such changes with braces

Comment: @Leonardo It does output on my machine. The default precision is 6.(OS X, clang++, libc++)

Answer (score 1):

One (ugly) way would be to cast it to `int` before the `cout` if you dont want to see the decimal places.

Something like (C style - still ok for primitive types)

```
cout << (int)flak << endl;
```

or ( [C++ style](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) - recommended, especially for non primitive types like classes)

```
cout << static_cast<int>(flak) << endl;
```

This will only change what `cout` sees, not the variable itself.

Comment: Is that very wise to change the type of variable in order to use it? And would it no longer be a double if I used it elsewhere in the code?

Comment: @Leonardo the type itself would still be a `double`, and the C++ way of doing a cast like that would be a `static_cast<T>()` where T is the type you want to cast it to. You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast) for more info on casts.

Comment: Yes I see that this does indeed work, and luckily the loss of precision will only affect the result of the call to that cout.

Comment: "C style - still ok for primitive types)" - what makes you say that? It ignores (and silently removes) `const`-ness and it doesn't express intent very well (you have to read the surrounding code to see why it was there). On top of that it is impossible to grep/search for it effectively in a large code base.