# How to cout a float number with n decimal places

Tags: c++, formatting, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

```
float a = 175.;
   cout << a;
```

If I run the previous code I'll get just 175, how can I cout the number with (for example) 3 decimal places even they were zeros .. How can I print "175.000" ?!

Comment: By the way, for clarity, I'd initialize it with `175.0f`. `175.` will produce a `double`. That's if you really don't want to change your variable type, which would be better in most cases.

Comment: @chris aha, thx for the tip

Answer (score 69):

You need [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
 std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << a;
```

These require following header:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Comment: Ahh, iostreams... seamlessly combining the speediness of a turtle and the beauty of Andrew LLoyd-Webber.

Comment: For future reference, if you're outputting multiple values, you only need to pass the manipulators once: `float a = 2.5; float b = 3.5; std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3); std::cout << a << std::endl; std::cout << b << std::endl;`

Comment: @MuhammadBarrima Please accept this answer if that's what you needed to show that this question is resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Try `setprecision`:

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout << setprecision(3) << a << endl;
```