# Division In C++ and java?

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2013

In C++ according to user input programmer able to find the final value is what double or int using this code.If 4/2 the answer is 2 Not 2.0. If 5/3 the answer is 1.66667 not 1.

```
float a;
float b;
cin >> a >> b;
float z = a / b;
cout << z << endl;
```

Simple thing is if user input is 2/4 the answer is 2 not 2.0. And if user input is 5/3 the answer is 1.66667 not 1 according to my c++ code. Can anybody do this same think in java Please?

Everybody know in calculator if we type 4/2 the answer is 2 not 2.0. And if we type 5/3 the answer is 1.66667 not 1. I just want to create something program like that i think now you understand me.

Comment: Users gave me minus points. But not answer. I am new in java. Why?

Comment: This code doesn't find out if the final value "is what double or int". The final value is a `float` because the division involves two `float`s.

Comment: Sir, you need to try this code. If user input is 2/4 answer is 2 not 2.0. And if user enter 5/3 answer is 1.66667 not 1.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The type is still `float`. If is to do with how `2.0` gets printed to the screen, not its type.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza have you tried using ```int```for ```a``` and ```b```? To me it is not very clear what your question is. So I am just poking around. If you want to do division without rest in java you would define the parameter as ```int```.

Comment: Simple thing is if user input is 2/4 the answer is 2 not 2.0. And if user input is 5/3 the answer is 1.66667 not 1 according to my c++ code. Can anybody do this same think in java Please?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza I added an answer explaining where your understanding is wrong.

Comment: Now you changed the meaning of the question completely.

Comment: Sir i update my question again read it. Or second think. You know in calculator if we type 4/2 the answer is 2 not 2.0. And if we type 5/3 the answer is 1.66667 not 1. I just want to create something program like that i think now you understand me.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677448/how-to-cout-a-float-number-with-n-decimal-places

Comment: Why can't you understand that it is just the way the number gets printed to the screen? I already explained that twice. Once in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is wrong because it is based on a misunderstanding. C++'s `auto` is a compile time construct. It cannot infer a type based on runtime information. In your example, the type of `z` in this code is `float`:

```
auto z = a/b;
```

This is because that is the type of the expression `a/b`, given that both `a` and `b` are of type `float`.

The issue is that `std::cout` is not printing any decimal places for a whole floating point number such as `2.0`. That is all. But you can tell it to do so. For example,

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);
```

Here's a working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    float a = 4;
    float b = 2;
    auto z = a / b;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

output:

> 2.0000

Comment: ok change auto to float still answer 4/2 is 2. I using visual studio 2013.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Yes, that's what I would expect, because `z` is float in both cases, so the behaviour should be the same.

Comment: Please one time read my question again. And help me to create something program like that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, then you could use a `Scanner` to get `float`(s) from `System.in` (the equivalent to `cin`), and then either a `float z` or a `double z` and then call `System.out.println()` like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
float a = scanner.nextFloat();
float b = scanner.nextFloat();
float z = a / b;
System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Java doesn't have an `auto` type.

Comment: So sir please tell me how to do something like auto?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza This is doing the same as `auto` in your code, i.e .declaring `z` to be of type `float`. I think you're misunderstanding what `auto` does.

Comment: Sir, but your code gave me answer 4/2 is 2.0 this is wrong. But in my code 4/2 the answer is 2. Please Compare.

Answer (score 0):

A simple double z = a/b; should work

Example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] arg){
    try{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.printf("Enter first Value:  ");
        double a = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("Enter second Value:  ");
        double b = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Division result: "+a/b);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include code to read input from the user then output the result.