# Static Cast (int) to (float) no decimals

Tags: c++

I'm trying to cast 2 integers into floats using `static_cast`. The problem is that when I do the math I get 4 instead of 4.00.

Below I have made an example of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 4,
        den = 1;

    cout << static_cast<float>(num) / static_cast<float>(den);
}
```

If I'm doing it incorrectly,then please indicate where i am wrong. Also please mention if there is a way to get 4.00 instead of just 4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677448/how-to-cout-a-float-number-with-n-decimal-places

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: What is the difference between 4.00 and 4? That said, in order to avoid those useless casts, create float literals: `float num = 4.0f;`. As a general rule, whenever you feel the temptation to add a cast to make code compile or to make it compile without warnings, you have been using the wrong type to begin with.

Comment: `4.00`, `4`, and `four`, are just different representations of the same value. When you divide two numbers, you get a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining what is written by Nathan and Eelke, 
use the Floating point Format flag [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) along with [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) Parametric manipulator, available in iomanip library.

Here is what your code look likes, after required changes :`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int num = 4,
    den = 1;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << 
            static_cast<float>(num) / static_cast<float>(den);
    return 0;
}
```