# Control exponent digits of a float using printf in gcc

Tags: c++, printf

I am using `mingw-gcc` and I want to print a `float`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  float a =1.23;
  std::cout << std::scientific << a << std::endl;
  printf("%e\n",a);
  return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
1.230000e+000
1.230000e+000
```

However float does not need more than two digits.
Is there any way in `gcc` to export number with 2 digit exponent?

```
1.230000e+00
1.230000e+00
```

Is there any similar function like [_set_output_format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fatw238.aspx) of Visual studio?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331723/how-to-control-the-number-of-exponent-digits-after-e-in-c-printf-e

Comment: @ewcz I want exactly the opposite. Two digit with mingw

Comment: this ? std::fixed and std::setprecision
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677448/how-to-cout-a-float-number-with-n-decimal-places

Comment: And that is apparently C++, not C. Mixing C++ iostreams with C functions on stdin is a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf I just wanted to show that `cout` and `printf` have the same behavior. It is obvious that this is not my original source.

Comment: @Olaf I mean `FLT_MAX_EXP`. You can refer to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/ for more information.

Comment: The standard library for none of the languages C or C++ are not part of the gcc compiler. So that is not relevant. And the behaviour for the C standard function `printf` is clearly defined in the standard. Similar for the C++ standard library (resp. which types you can pass to the `<<` method of an iostream to set the conversion behaviour).

Comment: Btw: for `printf`, you pass a `double`. It is not possible to pass a `float` to a variadic function. Read the man-page!

Comment: @Olaf the `gcc` compiler is a C and also a C++ compiler. If you read the title of the question it clearly refers to gcc. The question is not about the standard definition of `printf` or `cout`. It is clearly a question about the gcc C and C++ compiler and their non-standard capabilities.

Comment: @Olaf when `printf` prints a float the exponent will always start with a zero. So the question simply asks, if there is a way to avoid the extra character.

Comment: 1) The code is C++ **only** 2) The function you complain about are **not part of the compiler** - neither for C nor C++. They are not provided by gcc, but your platform.  3) The formating options are defined by the standards. RTFineManual! gcc just provides a freestanding implementation. The rest is a matter of your platform; the compiler is **no way** involved in that! As much as `_set_output_format` is an extension of the Windows standard C library, not of Visual Studio! Did you try using that function?

Comment: No, as I wrote: `printf` prints a `double`. **You cannot pass a `float` to it. Read about standard conversions. (not sure about C++, but I suspect it does the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at least as far as `printf` is concerned, it [seems](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Error-in-quot-e-quot-formatting-td1666219.html) that one can set the environment variable `PRINTF_EXPONENT_DIGITS` to `2` and compile with `-posix` switch (tested with mingw g++ 5.3.0 on clean install of Windows 10)

Comment: That depends on the libray and is not a matter of the compiler. It definitively is not standard.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and it works with `setenv` or `putenv`. It also applies to `cout`.