# Printing with ofstream using a custom locale (or how and why does locale affect precision)

Tags: c++, io, locale, iostream

I'm trying to **use a thousands separator** in some serialization code and I've opted for using a custom locale for my `ofstream`s. A minimal example using `cout` (the example uses `cout` instead of `ofstream` because I have to show you something onscreen) would be the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <locale>

class split_every_three : public std::numpunct<char>
{
protected:
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const { return '\''; }
    virtual std::string do_grouping() const { return "\03"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout.imbue( std::locale( std::locale::classic(), new split_every_three ) );
    
    std::cout << 1234589 << std::endl;
    std::cout << 12342.424134 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which **Outputs**:

> 1'234'589
>
> 12'342.4

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5c7894f5e2a6473)

The problem is the second line, i.e. *floating point numbers won't print all decimal digits*. **How can I fix it?** (and what have I done to break this?)

Comment: Is the problem with the second line of output that it's not printing enough decimal places or that the decimal separator isn't what you want?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677448/how-to-cout-a-float-number-with-n-decimal-places

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)