# How to return the real number from complex number

Tags: c++

I can seem to print the real part of a complex number using `printRe` in my class.

As a test I get complex number `p(1.0, 5.0)` where the real number is `1.0` and imaginary`number`5.0
`I would like to return real number, so`1.0`. 
The function should return

> real number(Real number is: 1.0)

But when I run my code, I get only

> "Real number is: "

Where is the problem 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
public:
    double a;
    double b;

    Complex(double re=0.0, double im=0.0){
        a = re;
        b = im;
    }

    Complex(const Complex &other){
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
    }

    void printRe(){
        printf("Real number is:", a);
    }

};


 //some operators +, -, *, /

int main(){

    Complex p(1.0, 5.0);
    p.printRe();

    return 0;

}
```

Would appreciate some help

Comment: Did you mean to use `cout` instead of `printf`?

Comment: Yes it works too :)

Comment: Why are you reinventing your own incompatible complex number type, instead of simply using `std::complex<double>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change the `printf` line to:

```
printf("Real number is: %f", a);
```

That should output the desired real part

I would suggest that you read about the `printf` function and how to properly use it in the following link: [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

In **C++** it is more common to use the `cout` rather then `printf` you can read about it also: [cout](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)

The `cout` way is:

```
std::cout << "Real number is:" << a << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to display/print to your standard output.

Try this (preferred method in C++):

```
std::cout << "Real number is: " << a << std::endl;
```

Or, Use correct [format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) with `printf`.

```
printf("Real number is: %f\r\n", a);
```

In printf, a format specifier follows this prototype:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

Where the specifier character at the end is the most significant component, since it defines the type and the interpretation of its corresponding argument.

```
f   Decimal floating point, lowercase                   392.65
F   Decimal floating point, uppercase                   392.65
e   Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), lowercase  3.9265e+2
E   Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), uppercase  3.9265E+2
g   Use the shortest representation: %e or %f           392.65
G   Use the shortest representation: %E or %F           392.65
a   Hexadecimal floating point, lowercase               -0xc.90fep-2
A   Hexadecimal floating point, uppercase               -0XC.90FEP-2
```

If you want to control the precision of float, you can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value) question for printf or visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677448/how-to-cout-a-float-number-with-n-decimal-places/14677503) for `cout`.