# Get a full double value

Tags: c++, vector, double

I add one double value from a file to a variable and push it into a vector, with format "338620.3478" , then after that I get the value from the vector, it just gets "338620", as it could not get all the double value.

So how can I get a full double value like the original format?

The Code:

```
struct Point {
    double x, y;

    bool operator <(const Point &p) const {
            return x < p.x || (x == p.x && y < p.y);
    }
```

};

```
    ifstream iFile("griddata.dat"); //read a file (grid)
string line; 
Point Grid; /
while(getline(iFile,line)) 
{
    unsigned pos = line.find(",");//the symbol is used to separate X and Y
    std::string strs = line.substr(0,pos); // get X
    std::string strs2 = line.substr(pos+1); // get Y

    Grid.x = atof(strs.c_str()); // get the first cooordinate X
    Grid.y = atof(strs2.c_str()); // get the second cooordinate Y

    // A list of coordinates of grid is stored into the vector gridPoints
    gridPoints.push_back(Grid); // adding the points of grid to vector

}
int j;

for(j=0;j<gridPoints.size();j++)
{
    //here i cannot get the full double value for gridPoints[j].x;
    //....it just gets "338620"

}
```

The format of file (griddata.dat):

**338620.3478,6196150.566**

Thank you!

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the same. Can you please post your code here, so that it will be easy to rectify the problem. :)

Comment: You should show the code you have. Otherwise, we can only guess at what is wrong.

Comment: @user2076858 you should be able to *edit* your question.

Comment: Are Points x and y double? Can we see a Point declaration?

Comment: I have just added, thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run it with a debugger? Can you see what values are contained in strs and strs2?

Comment: Yes the values of strs and strs2 are correct, just uncompleted when I want to retrieve them from the vector!

Comment: @user2076858 - You're not **SHOWING WHERE YOU USE THEM**. Just because you say you "retrieve" them in a for loop doesn't mean anything. Doing anything like `int a = gridPoints[0].x` could cause your truncation issue. Without more code, nobody knows. I vote this question should close until enough information is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Point` class is in the windows framework, I'm pretty sure it's members are `int` types.

Either way, your values are being cast to a type that isn't floating point and is being truncated.

Comment: I declared x and y as double values, you can see above, I have just added!

Comment: @user2076858 - Well what are you trying to do with the points once you get them? Where is that code? How do you _know_ the values are wrong?

Comment: Although, when I use cout << std::setprecision(15) << gridPoints[j].x , it displays correctly

Comment: I get those coordinates from a file, then push them into a vector and then put them to another function to process!

Comment: @user2076858 - Ok, so the numbers are actually right, but you're handling them wrong. User error, case closed.

Comment: What is my problem? can you help me to figure it out ? Thanks!

Comment: @user2076858 - You need to show where you are actually _using_ these values.

Comment: You can see at the for loop, that is where I will use my values by accessing these: gridPoints[j].x and gridPoints[j].y

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is retrieving the values (maybe with cout?? -->then you can use: cout.precision(15))

see: [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: My problem is not about printing out, it is about getting the value from the vector, with the full double value. Thanks