# Loss of precision on adding doubles?

Tags: c++, double, precision, addition

folks! I've encountered a little problem: I'm doing a simple addition with three double values. The result has a smaller precision than the used values.

```
double minutes = 3;
minutes = minutes / (24.0*60.0);  // contains 0.00208333
double hours = 3;
hours = hours / 24.0; // contains 0.125
double days = 3; // contains 3 

double age = days + hours + minutes; // result is 3.12708
```

I found no way to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: How do you check value of your variables?

Comment: What is the problem? Calculation seems ok. How do you print result? Do you want more digits printed?

Comment: note that: 1) depending on the way you output your values, you may not see all significant digits and 2) doubles are not able to exactly represent values like 0.1

Comment: Re: precision: all four print six significant digits. Where is the difference?

Comment: I get 3.127083333333333. Seems about right to me.

Comment: How do you get the result? `printf()` `%g` `%f`?

Comment: possible duplicate-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the calculation as what the comments on your post said.

If you'd like to see more precision consider looking up [setprecision()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

Comment: The calculation is correct, indeed. I validated this by using printf(). The loss of precision was been caused by outputting it by std::cerr or assigning it to a std::stringstream. setprecision did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. The significant figure of 0.00208333 and 3.12708 are both 6. This is a correct result.

Comment: In my case it WAS a problem, even if this may be no misbehaviour. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in order to get the value according to the desired precision we have to specify the limit of precision,here is my code which works fine ,hope it helps:

```
double minutes = 3;
minutes = minutes / (24.0*60.0);
double hours = 3;
hours = hours / 24.0; 
double days = 3;
double age = days + hours + minutes;
printf("%.8f",age);//here i have included the places of precision (.8)
```