# Loss of precision when using pow in C++

Tags: c++, precision, pow

10^1.64605 = 44.2639330165

However in C++ using `pow`:

```
double p = pow(10,1.64605) returns 44.2641.
```

Is there a way to increase the precision here? I tried casting both sides to `long double` but that didn't help either.

More interesting is:

```
cout<<p;
double a = -1.64605;
cout<<pow(10,-a);
p = pow(10, (-p));
cout<<p;
```

the output is:

```
-1.64605
44.2639
44.2641
```

Why?

Comment: Other than using a Bignum lib, probably there isn´t something to make it better.

Comment: when getting the 44.2641 what are you using to display it? debugger? cout? printf?

Comment: try adding a #include <iomanip> and then cout << setprecision(10) << p and cout << setprecision(10) << pow(10 -a)

Comment: which compiler/os are you using? I end up with 44.26393302 when using the setprecision call on the output.

Comment: It's just a precision problem. `pow(10, 1.646052)` is 44.2641.

Comment: Doing:
printf("%.12f\n",pow(10,1.64605));

I get:
44.263933016536

Comment: It's just an issue with formatting. I checked with Mathematica and my GCC gives the exact same output as Mathematica, and Mathematica has arbitrary precision. What exactly is the use case? If you had a real use case it would be easier to help. Precision with `pow` can sometimes be improved if you can rearrange the expression to use base 2 etc.

Comment: We can't see where you initialised p. Or what type it is. Do beware that 1.64605 is not exactly representable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cout` is truncating your double for display, but the value calculated by `pow` is probably at least as precise as you expect. For how to get more precision displayed in the console see:

[How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

I'll elaborate given the prodding by David.

You stated that `double p = pow(10,1.64605) returns 44.2641` but this is incorrect. It returns 44.26393301653639156; without any formatting specifiers this displays as 44.2639 (as you see later).

When you `cout` the original value of `p` in the second code snippit it displays `-1.64605` (due to reduced precision *formatting*) and you are assuming that it *is* exactly -1.64605 whereas it is actually somewhere between -1.64605115... and -1.64605213..., which *does* evaluate to 44.2641 in the expression `cout << pow(10, (-p));`

Comment: This scratches at the surface but doesn't really get to the bottom of the issue. For instance see for yourself what `cout << pow(10,1.64605)` outputs even with full precision.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. If you're talking about `44.2641` he obviously just mixed up the results of his program when he posted.

Comment: No he did not. The explanation is exactly as described in my answer.

Comment: I mean that he wrote `44.2641` was the result of his original calculation when it was actually the result of his second.

Comment: That's wrong. `pow(10,1.64605)` returns `44.2639`. It's `pow(10, (-p))` that returns `44.2641`. Which begs the question as to what value is `p`. It's all explained in my answer.

Comment: OK, now your answer is accurate. The voting is very odd, but there you go! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be found by examining `p`. You did not show how it was initialized.

You will find that `p != a`, even though they appear to be the same when you print them to the console. When you printed to the console you only printed the first 6 significant decimal digits. Print both values to greater precision and you will see that they are not equal.

You said that:

```
double p = pow(10,1.64605);
```

evaluates to `44.2641`. But that is not true. If you actually execute that code you will see that.

```
double p = pow(10,1.64605);
cout << p;
```

outputs `44.2639`.

Your code differs slightly from that above. It is:

```
cout << p;
p = pow(10, (-p));
cout << p;
```

Output the original value of `p` to full precision and all will be revealed.