# C++ How to get fixed digit after decimal in cout<<

Tags: c++, precision

C++ How to get fixed digit after decimal in output????
Like f=123.456789
I want to show 123.46 in output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: So you took the `cout` path. You deserve a punishment for this and the punishment will take the form of C++ formatting. You'll suffer this pain for the rest of your C++ programming life.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **setprecision()** method in C++.

```
cout<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(2)<<f;
```

Comment: I'd downvote the answer given how ugly and wrong this code is on so many levels. I won't just because it is, unfortunately, what C++ texts recommend to do. But I really cannot upvote it, that's too much.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use **printf** function, make sure that you include **stdio.h** file to use it,
printf("%0.2f",f);
Here %f is format specifier(float) and 0.2 between '%' and 'f' is used to set precision upto two decimal places.

Comment: Well in the title the OP asked using with `cout` and `printf` can't be used with `cout`...

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `boost::format`

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>

cout << boost::format("%.2f") % f << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd require I/O manipulator for decimal precision.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    double foo = 123.456789L;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```