# Setting decimal points using #iostream

Tags: c++

I need to have my `cout` have two digits after the decimal point, i.e.:

the value:  2.3 to become: 2.30.
I have found some solutions using `iomanip`, etc.

However I need a simple way to do this with only `iostream`.

```
centage = (abc/ cdf)*100;
cout << "total is "<<abc<<" of "<<cdf<<", or "<<centage <<"%";
```

Comment: `cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << centage;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: @erip Requires iomanip and OP seems to really want to make things hard on themselves.

Comment: @user4581301 Eep! Didn't see the "no iomanip" part.

Comment: No worries, @erip . You have the right solution. OP wants simple, but pulls out the tools that make it anything but hard. All I can come up with is some god awful kludge like this `std::cout << (int)val << '.' << (int)(val *10 + .05) %10 << (int)(val *100 + .05) %10 << std::endl;`

Comment: Quick reality check, Bardi. Any reason why iomanip is off the table or is this just an exercise in masochism?

Comment: @user4581301 I was thinking about converting to a string and basically doing that, too.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::setprecision()` manipulator is just convenience for setting the precision together with other outputs. You can set the precision directly on the stream, too:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [*stream manipulators*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/):

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << centage;
```

Which will display 2 digits after the decimal point, as in `fixed` notation the manipulator `setprecision()` specifies the number of the digits after the decimal point.

I doubt that `iostream` alone provides directly the facilities to temper with 
decimal precision. So, in my opinion there is no simpler way besides the already provided manipulators.

The other unorthodox solution is to do something using string manipulation, where for example you can convert to string and concatenate some (meaningless) 0's till you get the wanted "precision" and return the result as string.

Answer (score 0):

here you use only `iostream`, but instead of `cout` use `printf` like that:

```
printf("%.2f\n", centage);
```