# Result is only 5 decimal places even with long double (in c++)

Tags: c++, pi

I wrote a c++ program to calculate pi using the infinite expansion for pi/4. I've used long double but still i get pi = 3.14158 . Where is the extra decimal chopped off. How to correct it?
 So is this is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    long double pi=1,si,i;

    for(i=1;i<100000;i++)
    {
        si = (pow(-1.0 ,i))/(2*i+1);
        pi += si;
    }

    pi*=4.0;
    cout<<"  "<< pi <<" \n ";
}
```

Comment: `std::cout` is chopping extra decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is not the actual accuracy of the computed number, but in the formatting of your displayed output. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout) answer for details.