# how to subtract 50e-12 from 50.5e-12 in c++ using double data type?

Tags: c++, math, precision

I have a code as follows:

```
double a = 50e-12;
double b = 50.5e-12;
double c = b - a;
std::cout<<"value of a,b and c is : "<<a<<" " <<b<<" "<<c<<std::endl;
```

Now my output is :
    value of a,b and c is : 0.0000000001 0.0000000001 0.0000000000

I can see that my operands are rounded off and because of which I get a 0 as the output although I expect a 0.5.

Can someone help me with this.?

Comment: Note that real values, and printed values may differ...

Comment: Use proper formatting for output, not default one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Comment: Not all numbers can be represented as `double`.

Comment: you may be "seeing" that they're rounded, but they're actually not - the subtraction will be working fine.  This is an output problem, not a calculation one.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 6):

Under the circumstances, it seems to me like it makes the most sense to print the result out using (C++'s approximation of) scientific notation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() { 
    double a = 50e-12;
    double b = 50.5e-12;
    double c = b - a;

    std::cout << std::scientific << c << "\n";
}
```

This produces about what you'd expect:

```
5.000000e-13
```

While you certainly can just print out all 13 or 15 digits (or whatever) in decimal, when your input is in (pseudo-) scientific notation, it probably makes the most sense to print the output the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) before printing your values:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1)
          << "value of a, b and c is : " << a << " " << b << " " << c << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the output stream how many digits to display.  Here's how you can tell it to use the max number of digits for a double.

```
#include <limits>    

cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10);
```