# How to print a full double precision by google glog

Tags: c++, precision, glog

I am try to print a double variable `a` like this.

```
double a;
//some statements for a
LOG(INFO) << a;
```

How can I print `a` using full precision?

Comment: Try with [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try

```
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

double a = 3.141592653589793238;
LOG(INFO) << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 15 ) << a;
```

If that doesn't work you can convert it to an `std::string` and use `std::stringstream`

```
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream 
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision 

double a = 3.141592653589793238;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 15 ) << a;
LOG(INFO) << ss.str();
```

Alternatively, if you want full precision you can use one of the above with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout).

The first method is more than likely to be the most efficient way to do it.