# C++ precision in double

Tags: c++, double, precision, cout

I have something like

```
double d1=4.0;
double d2=8.0;
```

I am trying to print sum of those double values using `cout`.
Is it possible to print the sum with exact precision without setting the precision?

If the values are

```
double d1=4.23;
double d2=4.0;
```

The sum should print `8.23` without any additional zeros.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Comment: @nephtes OP said _without setting the precesion_

Comment: So many questions recently about wanting exact results with inexact representations.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3):

Native floating values do not work this way.

As soon as you set a `double`:

```
double d1=4.23;
```

Then the actual value that `d` gets set to is, approximately, 4.2300000000000004263256

This happens right off the bat. Do not pass Go. Do not collect $200. It's too late, even before you compute the sum, because 4.23 is not a representable number in base 2 floating point representation.

The only way to achieve exact precision non-integer math is to use a library that's specially designed for this purpose, such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)'s `mpq_t` rational numbers.

Comment: @FirstStep - thanks for pointing out my typo; I actually ran a quick test, rather than compute this myself, and fat-fingered everything... But the basic point is still true.