# How to export higher precision output files from ASSIMP?

Tags: c++, assimp

When exporting meshes with [`assimp`](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) through code as shown below I receive very limited precision output. Is there a way in `assimp` to increase export precision? *(Nothing hints at this in the documentation.)*

```
void export(aiScene* scene, const std::string & outputFile)
{
    Assimp::Exporter exporter;

    // exporter.mOutput.precision(16); ???

    exporter.Export(scene, "obj", outputFile);
}
```

Output in the `.obj` file will contain no more than 6 digits per value:

```
v  557760 4.07449e+06 -49.1995
v  557760 4.07449e+06 -49.095
v  557760 4.0745e+06 -49.0082
v  557760 4.0745e+06 -49.1127
```

When looking at the actual exporter class (`ObjExporter.cpp`) all data is written through a public `stringstream`:

```
public:
    std::ostringstream mOutput, mOutputMat;

[...]

mOutput << "# " << vp.size() << " vertex positions" << endl;
for(const aiVector3D& v : vp) {
    mOutput << "v  " << v.x << " " << v.y << " " << v.z << endl;
}
mOutput << endl;
```

Is there a way I could increase the `stringstream` precision (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) without having to change the `assimp` source?

Comment: 6 is the default precision for streams, did you try using std::setprecision (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)?

Comment: no I did not try that, but could I just do that in my code (that statically links with `assimp`) ? (to be clear - I was looking for a solution without changing code in `assimp`, but this may not be realistic)

Comment: Maybe the format doesn't allow more precision?

Comment: No, OBJ, STL, PLY are all text based formats - you can use much higher precision that 6 digits - it's an implementation error in `assimp` that I am fixing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the different exporter classes in detail it becomes apparent that some of them indeed have set a **higher** precision for the `stringstream` internally, but there is **no** way to (globally) define this or externally pass a request in for a higher precision export.

Technically, you may be able to instantiate the actual export class and update the `stringstream` manually (since it's a public member variable), but this makes the export a lot more complicated and the point of using `assimp` was to easily export to different formats.

I thus have updated `assimp` to export higher precision floating point values as (for example) discussed here: [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)