# C++ cout prints " inf " after operations between two big decimal number (long double)

Tags: c++, c++11

My program takes a vector of long doubles as input (`vector<long double>`) and calculates different solutions using some methods.

Everything works fine until I try these two numbers: 1.18973e+4932 and 1.18973e+4932.

It outputs the following:

```
<2: 1.18973e+4932 1.18973e+4932 >

Min: 1.18973e+4932
Max: 1.18973e+4932
Range: 0
Midrange: inf
Median: inf
Mean: inf
Variance: inf
StdVariance : inf
```

After some researches, I found out that the value is exceeding the space in memory available for its own type.

**So the question is:** is it possible to handle this inside my code? Or the only solution is to input a smaller number?

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout

Comment: [mcve]'s make solutions way easier, and more reliable.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: First, there is no guarantee that `long double` is larger than `double`. Second, whether you use `double` or `long double`, there are a finite number of them whereas there are uncountably many real numbers. So, some will not be representable in the chosen format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling ***might*** help depending on what the compiler chooses to do with your code:

```
$ cat s.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long double v = 1.18973e+4932L;

    std::cout << "Midrange: " << (v + v) / 2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "Midrange again: " << (v/2 + v/2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

$ g++ s.cpp -Wall -O2 -o s

$ ./s
Midrange: inf
Midrange again: 1.18973e+4932
```

You can also avoid calculating anything when the sample `min` and `max` are equal, and just set *mean*, *midrange* and *median* equal to either value, and *range*, *variance* and *standard deviation* to `0.0` without messing around any further.

Comment: Your post was helpful but it covered only one test case. Now I found another case in which that happen and I can't understand why.        `<2: 1.18973e+4932 1.18973e+4932 >  
  
Min: 5.94865e+4931  
Max: 1.18973e+4932  
Range: 5.94865e+4931  
Midrange: 8.92298e+4931  
Median: 2.97433e+4931  
Mean: inf  
Variance: inf  
Std_deviation : inf  `.   here the second number is the first devided by 2 and since they're not equal the calculations are executed and the result overflows.  How would you solve it?