# Converting Matlab code to C++ (no image processing is included in the code)

Tags: c++, matlab

I want to convert my Matlab code to c++. I did search for it but I got more confused.
 Could anyone show me the simplest way to do that? If any information about code is needed please let me know. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Matlab is a specialized language with a huge library of built-in functions.  C++ is a general-purpose programming language *that does not have those functions*.  There is no automatic conversion to plain C++.  What you need to do is look for a math library for C++ that does what you want then learn to use it.

Comment: But I have heard that there are some ways to convert Matlab code to c++. as Matlab coder...@DaveS

Comment: What have you heard?  What does a Google search tell you?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html It says that it is possible for some functions @DaveS

Comment: If you pay enough, Matlab has a utility that cranks out C code. It's actual value depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: What about c++? @user4581301

Comment: You pray the C code integrates well with your C++ code.

Comment: Isn't there any free choice? Or any software to do that?@user4581301

Comment: Is this link related to what you say about paying matlab? @user4581301

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/what-are-code-acceleration-and-code-generation-from-matlab.html and then "C Code Generation at the Command Line (MATLAB Coder)"

Comment: I am not sure if there is an easy way to do this except with [Matlab Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html). You can write your own mexFunction and compile it in Matlab. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903860/how-to-compare-results-between-c-and-matlab/43912992#43912992).

Comment: One more question: Is it less time consuming to run a code in c++ than matlab?@kedarps

Comment: Do you answer for above question? @user4581301

Comment: Too many variables to answer that, I'm afraid. You can write awesome or crappy code in either. What is your goal? Produce an executable that does not require any bits and pieces of Matlab so you can move it around to other, Matlab-less computers? Raw performance?

Comment: I have written my code in matlab. The code is really slow. So I decide to change it to c++ code to make it faster. I want to understand if it really makes the code faster to run or not @user4581301

Comment: Might be worth finding out why the Matlab code is really slow because if the algorithm is just plain slow, porting it to C++ won't help.

Comment: Then why do people prefer to write heavy simulations in c++? @user4581301

Comment: What I'm saying is if the algorithm is slow in Matlab it will be slow in C++. On the other hand if you implemented a fast algorithm in a manner that is inefficient in Matlab, you may be able to fix up the Matlab code to take advantage of what Matlab does well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab has a tool that converts your Matlab .m to .mex and may also generate a C/C++ code, see https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-coder

Comment: There is no c++ in the link

Comment: The page you linked to said "C/C++" because C++ compilers also compile C.  That page links to this page http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/what-are-code-acceleration-and-code-generation-from-matlab.html  which links to "C Code Generation at the Command Line (MATLAB Coder)"

Comment: "C++ compilers also compile C" Mostly. For a quick example of when they don't watch what happens with the `auto` keyword.

Comment: From the 'codegen' documentation ... If you specify C++, MATLAB Coder™ wraps the C code into .cpp files so that you can use a C++ compiler and interface with external C++ applications. It does not generate C++ classes.