# What is the actual value of adding 0.1 and 0.2?

Tags: c++, g++

For this C++ program...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  float d = 0.1;
  float e = 0.2;
  float result = d + e;
  bool is_equal = (result == 0.3);

  cout << result << endl;
  cout << is_equal << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The answer printed to the console is...

```
0.3
0
```

Questions:

- Why isn't the value of `result` equal to `0.30000000000000004`, like it is in any other languages I've used (Ruby, JavaScript, Elixir)?
- If the printed `result` is `0.3`, why isn't `result` equal to `0.3`?
- What is the actual value of `result`?

Comment: It depends on how you convert it to a string.

Comment: The value is indeed likely `0.30000000000000004` its just that the default precision of `std::cout` for `float` is not printing that many decimals. You can see how to modify that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: `<<` for floating point does some polite formatting for you. [Use `std::setprecision` to make it show more digits.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: You can always inspect `result` value in debugger. Also using `==` to compare floating point number with literal (or two floating point numbers) is not a good idea.

Comment: Also handy: [`std::boolalpha` for when you want nice true/ false output instead of 1/0.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)

Comment: Referencing the question that my question is (apparently) a duplicate of, here's an example of printing w/ precision -- https://gist.github.com/amorphid/37e935f679afcf6addeebbdd13822276

Comment: The first duplicate question was a poor choice. The reason why your comparison fails is because floating point math is fundamentally broken. See the second duplicate question. In fact, the second question also uses the fact that 0.1 + 0.2 is not 0.3, as an example.

Comment: removed "Handling doubles with large integer parts" from the dupe list: `0` is not a large integer part, and that question has little to do with this one