# Unsure about a line of code that outputs a double or int

Tags: c++

I am running into a bit of a confusion about one line in this code:

```
const int maxNum = 4;
int count = 1;
double num;
double total = 0;
double average;

while(count <= maxNum) {
    cout << "please enter a number: " << endl;  
    cin >> num;
    total = total + num;
    cout << "The total is now: " << total << endl;
    count++;
}

cout << "total of 4 digits is: " << total << endl;
//count--;
average = total/count;
cout << "the average of 4 digits is: " << average << "." << endl;
```

My question is in regards to `count--;`:

With `count--;` the average (double) has a decimal point.
But when I remove that line of code, the average is shown as only a integer.

What is the significance of this line?

Comment: Wrong question. The question you should have asked would be: How do I format floating point I/O stream output?

Comment: `average` is ALWAYS a `double`. That is how typed languages work. If you are referring to why it contains no decimals, that may be due to your numbers added being divided evenly with no remainder. I think what you are asking is how to format your output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout should have your answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Answer (score 2):

After the while loop

```
while(count <= maxNum){
    //...
    count++;
}
```

`count` becomes equal to `maxNum + 1` that is to `5` though only `maxNum` numbers were entered. So you need to decrease `count` before using it in calculating of the average. Though it would be better to use just `maxNum` instead of `count`.

It seems that diviting total by `5` you get an integer number.

Comment: I bet OP used 1 2 3 4 to test ;)

Comment: uhh that makes sense. because the count within the while loop operates 4 times, the initial value is 1, so 1 + 4 would be 5.

it would be better to use maxNum instead of count. you're right!

thanks!!