# The process will stop when dif==0 but when dif==-0.000000 it doesn't stop

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm trying to code a program to write a fraction `m/n` as a sum of different Egyptian Fractions (EFs) with the minimal number of EFs.

Here is my full code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float a,b,sum=0,sct[100000];
    float arr=1; 
    int stt=0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    while(sum!=a/b){  
        sum=sum+(1/arr);
        float dif=a/b-sum;
        printf("%f - sum = %f - dif = %f\n",arr,sum,dif);
        if(dif>=0){
            sct[stt]=arr;
            cout<<"1/"<<arr<<"\n"; 
            stt++;
        } else {  
            sum=sum-(1/arr);
        }
        arr++;
    }
    cout<<stt<<"\n";
    for(int m=0;m<stt;m++) cout<<sct[m]<<" ";
}
```

You can see well that if `dif==0` then the process will end. But when `arr==3`, I get `dif==-0.000000` but the process doesn't end!

Output Caption:

[image]

I tried to fix it but all my efforts are useless. Do you know what should I change in my code?

Any help will be high appreciated!

Comment: Floating point numbers are *not* exact. You generally always want to use `<=` or `>=` when comparing `float`s or `double`s - or compare with some epsilon - very rarely is `==` what you want. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout - for debugging purposes.

Comment: FWIW, instead of an image, rather copy the text from the console and post that. Just format it as code and it will be readable.

Comment: Don't include implementation details (`<bits/stdc++.h>`), include proper C++ headers.

Comment: Omg, I tried and I am still not successful :(

Answer (score 1):

Floating point comparisons usually won’t work, because `==` means “exactly zero”, while you only care that it’s “close enough” to zero. Write a function to check for loop termination:

```
bool isNear(float f, float g) {
  return abs(f-g)<=((abs(f)+abs(g))/1e8);
}
```

And use it:

```
while (!isNear(sum, a/b)) …
```

Comment: Oh my god, it does not work :(