# Displaying Long Numbers C++

Tags: c++

I don't need to do any calculations just print out the numbers.

```
double n1 = 1000000.5985;
double n2 = 9999999.0;
double n3 = 678300.893;
```

When I try

```
cout << n1 << n2 << n3;
```

I get 1e+006 1e+007 678301

How do I get it to print the whole number without converting to a string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setprecision()` from `<iomanip>`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double f = 1000000.5985;
   cout << f << endl;
   cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << f <<endl;
   cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << f << endl;
   cout << fixed << setprecision(9) << f << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
1e+06
1000000.598500
1000000.59850
1000000.598500000
```

Comment: Doesn't work when I try the number 1000000.5985 please help

Comment: Edited the code with `setprecision` with `fixed`. Try it. This ensures exactly as many digits as specified in `setprecision()` after the decimal point.