# handling small numbers in c++ with exp/expl functions

Tags: c++, function, numbers, exponential, exp

I'm in C++ and I'm using the exponential function `exp()` from `<cmath>`. I'm dealing with very small number, so I tried to use also `expl()` fucntion, but the (incorrect) result is always the same: 1.
I show you a very quick example. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

```
#include <cmath>
...
long double a= 1.40543081e-8;
cout << "exp(-a)= " << exp(-a) << endl; 
cout << "expl(-a)= " << expl(-a) << endl;
```

The output is:

```
exp(-a)= 1  
expl(-a)= 1
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The result is correct, it's only printed with too few decimal places, thus getting rounded to 1. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout).

Comment: If you know the value is very small, use expm1 to avoid loss of significance.