# How to deal with long floating numbers the program doesn't support?

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to read a bunch of constants of a text-file in C++ using the `<fstream>` library. The constants are 16 decimal places long, or 16 digits after the decimal point. Now, whenever I try to read those digits, the program  truncates it to 6 decimal places whether I use the datatypes `double` or `long double`.

The program goes on something like this -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<double> test;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("constants.txt");
    double num;
    while(fin>>num){
        test.push_back(num);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<64; i++){
        cout<<test[i]<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the constants, from the `constants.txt` file go on something like `0.2599210498948732`, but when I try to print it using the program, it truncates it to `0.259921`. What do i to print the entire of the 16 digit long decimal number?

Comment: The default output format uses just 6 decimal places.  If you want more, you have to tell the I/O streams what to do.

Comment: `std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << test[i]`

Comment: Does [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout) help you out? If yes, let us know and we'll mark the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like setting the precision seems to be working. You can mark it as duplicate. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std::cout.precision(). The limit precision of long double is 18.

```cpp
long double number = 0.2599210498948732;
cout.precision(16);
cout << number;
```

Comment: Yes! Just learned that using `setprecision` on `long double ` is the solution to my problem. Thank you for the answer!