# C++ double divided by double results in rounded number

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following calculation:

```
    double a = 141150, b = 141270, c = 141410;
    double d = (a + b + c) / 3;
    cout << d << endl;
```

The output shows `d = 141277`, whereas `d` should be `141276.666667`. The calculation consists of double additions and a double division. Why am I getting a result that is rounded up?? By the way `d = (a + b + c) / 3.0` doesn't help.

However in another similar calculation, the result is correct:

```
    double u = 1, v = 2, x = 3, y = 4;
    double z = (u + v + x + y) / 4;
```

z results in `2.5` as expected. These two calculations are essentially the same, but why different behaviors?

Lastly, I know C++ automatically truncates numbers casted to lower precision, but I've never heard of automatic rounding. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Try `cout << std::fixed << d << endl`

Comment: I believe the default precision is 6 decimal digits.

Comment: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b916049233b5cb67)

Comment: You need to distinguish between the precision of the double itself and the precision of the output stream...

Comment: Instead of setting `std::fixed` (or combined with) you also might increase the stream's precision, e.g. `std::setprecision(15)` – side note: with 20, rounding effects of double get visible...

Comment: Thanks guys it was very helpful, now I will read more about streams

Comment: The **stream inserter** `operator<<` for floating-point types, by default, displays six digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout) you can find multiple answers on the same problem with code snippets as examples. It does include what the guys said in the comments

Comment: you should raise a duplicate flag rather than creating an answer if you find another question the same

Comment: Sorry dude, not quite familiar with how to do so. Thanks for the note @AlanBirtles