# how to round a number to N decimal places in C++? (correction)

Tags: python, c++

I want to round a number (6.756765345678765) to 10 decimal places , but it returns '6.75677', although it could returns '6.7567653457'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double rounded(double number, int N)
{
    return round(number * pow(10, N)) / pow(10, N); // i've chanched float to double
}

int main()
{
    double value = 6.756765345678765; 
    cout << rounded(value, 10)
}
```

I'd like to see a function returns rounded number

Frankly speaking, I'd see an alternative of function 'round' in python

```
print(round(6.756765345678765, 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setprecision(10)` function of `<iomanip>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double value = 6.756765345678765; 
    cout << setprecision(10) << value;
}
```

Output:

```
6.756765346
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not your code. Your issue is the `cout` itself. You have to set its precision to print the double correctly. Here is a previous question related to your issue: [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

You can try the same code but with: `cout.precision(X)` where X is the maximum precision you want to display.

Comment: yeah it works, to round a number to 10 decimal places, I have to use 'cout.precision(11)'